# Bootstrap Select With Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **Bootstrap v3** and Codeigniter... In my app, there is two select option element, for choosing state and city. I'm using ajax and when a state is selected, populated second element with related cities:

```
$('#state').change(function(){
    var state_id = $('#state').val();
    if(state_id != ""){
      var post_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/get_cities/" + state_id;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        cache: true,
        success: function(cities){ //calling the response json array 'cities'
            $('#city').empty();
            $.each(cities, function(id, city){
                $('#city').append($("<option></option>").val(id).text(city));
            }); //each
         }
     }); //ajax
    }
}); //change
```

everything is good, just bootstrap select option element has a bad view on other browsers! (it's good just on chrome). so I decide to use bootstrap-select plugin: [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)
**My question is**: How could I populate second select option for cities? In fact, It will be populate, but so the bootstrap-select using dropdown, I must also populate it.
thanks for attention...

**EDITED:**

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="state" id="state">
 <!--in a foreach loop, echo all states with the proper value-->
</select>

<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="city" id="city">
</select>
```

**SOLVED:** I find the solution... simply add one line after populating select element!

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: can we see the html? - your question is more about bootstrap-select but there is no bootstrap-select code in the code you have pasted. as it goes you haven't really given us a clear problem to solve. that said - is the post_url being set correctly? is the ajax request made? is the success function called? what is 'cities' at that point? what is id and city when you loop through cities? does #city exist? i.e. just put some breakpoints/logging as you step through the flow

Comment: Thanks for attention. I think it is clear, because as I said, everything work good. the url is correct and... cities are json response (as I said in code, as comment), and each city have an id and a name (city). and in a loop, the option elements will be set. In bootstrap-select plugin, just sholud add 'selectpicker' class to select element.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question the city select will populate from the AJAX but it loses the selectpicker functionality?

Maybe that is due to the $('#city').empty() line?

If so: then could you try starting again with a new select? E.g.

replace: $('#city').empty();

with this code

```
$('#city').remove();
$('#state').after( $('<select></select>').addClass('form-control selectpicker').attr({'id' : 'city', 'name' : 'city'}) );
//do your ajax stuff and add the options
$('#city').selectpicker(); //initialise it
```

*untested

(If the above works it may be overkill and you could simply solve the problem by re-initialising the city select after re-loading it. I.e you'd just need the $('#city').selectpicker(); line).

Comment: Forget 'select picker' for a moment. Every time that a state option is changed, first the select options for cities will be empty and then populate with new ones (I do this in function, in success part). Now, 'select picker'... this plugin uses dropdown structure, and add some ul and li for a select element. in this situation, when I change state option, my old options for cities will be generate correctly, BUT... because viewing is done by dropdown and I couldn't regenerate that (based on changed option in state) this will not show!!!

Comment: Good news! Thanks for letting us know.